# WKWebView open src in html

Tags: ios, wkwebview

Hello I'm trying to load html with the following element to WKWebView:

```
<iframe align=\"middle\"
 allowtransparency=\"\"
 frameborder=\"0\"
 height=\"820px\"
 id=\"\"
 scrolling=\"no\"
 seamless=\"\"
 src=\"//my.site.ru/files_static/edd/2016/speech_countries/6/first.html\" 
 width=\"100%\">
</iframe>
```

WKWebView can't load the content and it shows an empty screen instead. But if I add https or http to the src, the element loads successfully:

```
<iframe align=\"middle\"
 allowtransparency=\"\"
 frameborder=\"0\"
 height=\"820px\"
 id=\"\"
 scrolling=\"no\"
 seamless=\"\"
 src=\"http://my.site.ru/files_static/edd/2016/speech_countries/6/first.html\" 
 width=\"100%\">
</iframe>
```

I searched for some property to set default protocol for WKWebView in WKWebView, WKPreferences, WKWebViewConfiguration but did not find anything.
Can WKWebview load html by link without a protocol?

Found an answer: you need to set baseUrl string when calling loadHtmlString

Comment: please make proper html format please check it https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/8cy0lh/how_do_you_load_an_iframe_in_wkwebview_locally/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make html content relative to a "base" url...

I'm assuming you're using `.loadHTMLString(...)`?

If so, change your `src=` to:

```
src=\"/files_static/edd/2016/speech_countries/6/first.html\"
```

and change your `.loadHTMLString()` to:

```
theWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: URL(string: "http://my.site.ru"))
```

or `https://my.site.ru`